# Using Conditional operator on constants

Tags: excel, vba

I have a constant which is set to True or False. How can I use a conditional operator on the constant?

For e.g. I want to do someting like this:

```
Public Const IsMale = true

If IsMale = True Then
    ...
Else
    ...
End If
```

But I get following compile error:

```
Compile Error: Invalid Outside Procedure
```

Comment: For the compiler the above is like writing `If True=True Then` ..

Comment: Changing the runtime behavior based on a constant? Smells like bad code to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the const `IsMale` at module level and don't assign value to it later(Not permitted although).

Below is sample code

```
Public Const IsMale = True

Sub test()

    If IsMale Then
        MsgBox "Male"
    Else
        MsgBox "FeMale"
    End If

End Sub
```

Or

If you want to define locally use below(remove public keyword)

```
Sub test()

 Const IsMale = True

    If IsMale Then
        MsgBox "Male"
    Else
        MsgBox "FeMale"
    End If

End Sub
```

Read more [below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeO0v.gif)

[image]